# f1_score: ValueError: Can't handle mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass-multioutput?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
#coding=utf-8
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1],
                   [1, 0, 1],
                   [1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0]])
# If you change any of the following arrays to a number other than 0 and 1, you # will get an error.
y_pred = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 2, 1],  ####error
                   [1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0]])
print (f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro'))
#The following situation will arbitrarily modify the number, no error will be #reported.
z_true = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3])
z_pred = np.array([1, 0, 2, 4, 3])
print (f1_score(z_true, z_pred , average='micro'))
```

#

This problem is different from other similar errors.

```
#############################################################
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmWorkSpace/ceshi/GridSearch/Grid Search.py", line 20, in <module>
    print (f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro'))
  File "D:\python(2.7.9)\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 639, in f1_score
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "D:\python(2.7.9)\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 756, in fbeta_score
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "D:\python(2.7.9)\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 956, in precision_recall_fscore_support
    y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
  File "D:\python(2.7.9)\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 82, in _check_targets
    "".format(type_true, type_pred))
ValueError: Can't handle mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass-multioutput
```

Comment: Why do you change 1 to 2? Do you understand what is represented by the format? From where do you get this output?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by changing the 1 to 2 in the y_pred? For multi-label y_pred, you should use one hot encoding where each column denotes a class, and each entry only takes 0/1.
The error stems from mixing up binary encoding with class labels.

Comment: The reason for the occurrence of 2 is to use GaussianNB(), which is predicted to have non zero and 1 .

Comment: Is your y_pred the prediction from GaussianNB? If yes then it should give you a list of class labels, whose number is the same as the input number of classes. For multi-label you can run that on each column, but the prediction for each class should be binary. If you could provide a complete training code and reproduce the problem, that would be more helpful for other people to understand your problem.